# finding all the HtmlInputCheckBox controls with master.pages with recursion

Tags: c#, asp.net

I thought this would work. But it's not working.  It's never getting inside of if (c is HtmlInputCheckBox)

```
private string GetAllCheckBoxes(ControlCollection controls)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (Control c in controls)
    {
        if (c.HasControls())
        {
            GetAllCheckBoxes(c.Controls);
        }
        else
        {
            if (c is HtmlInputCheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
                if (cb.Checked)
                {                                
                    sb.Append(cb.ID + "_1");                                
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(cb.ID + "_0");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return sb.ToString();

}
```

update: c is throwing somesort of error.

```
Parent = {InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)(c.Parent)))).InnerText' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}
```

Comment: Did u trace the code using break points? Is `c` as you expected?

Comment: well it seems that c is throwing some sort of error.  Parent = {InnerText = '((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl)(((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)(c.Parent)))).InnerText' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'}

Comment: Can you show me more of your code please? how do you fill `controls`?

Comment: @user713813: The InnerText will always throw that exception when debugging and the control has child controls. You can ignore that; it won't affect your code any — as long as you're aren't trying to use InnerText on a control with child controls, which you aren't here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HtmlInputCheckBox` and `CheckBox` are different classes and do not inherit from the other. An `is` test on one won't work for the other and vice versa. Sounds like the control is probably an instance of a `CheckBox` so change the conditional to:

`if (c is CheckBox)`